# floated div inside another floated div problem

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have problem with floating divs.

Current html markup:

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        1
        <div style="float: left;">
            3
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;">
            4
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        2
    </div>        
    <div style="clear: both;" />
</div>
```

Block 2 appears in browsers as a part of Block 1, under Block 3 and 4. What's the problem?

Comment: Good question. What's the problem? What do you want it to appear as?

Comment: I'd like them to appear as separate blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div`s are not self-closed tags (such as `<br />` and `<hr />` and `<img />`), and closing them in your way, will not close them really!!!
In fact your code should look like this:

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        1
        <div style="float: left;">
            3
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;">
            4
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        2
    </div>        
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the div after block 4 this way:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, everything worked for me. Still don't understand why <div /> construction doesnt' work in browsers. It's silly.

Comment: <div>s are designed to contain items, so they need a separate closing tag. I too have thought that the standard practice of using an empty DIV was silly, but I have done, and still do it sometimes. It is better to create a class that clears the float using the :after psudo class and use it in an existing element where ever you need a clear. (ie a div that has content and is currently floating)